# Glide : How to get the error bitmap?

Tags: android, android-glide

By using the Glide image loader library, you are able to be notified if the began loading has succeeded.

```
Glide
      .with(this)
      .load(uri)
      .asBitmap()
      .listener(mRequestListener)
      .into(imageView);
```

It works well, because you can get the bitmap loaded by Glide on the onResourceReady callback method of the RequestListener class. Now use an error placeholder:

```
Glide
      .with(this)
      .load(uri)
      .asBitmap()
      .listener(mRequestListener)
      .error(R.drawable.error_image)
      .into(imageView);
```

What if I want to get the error image?
When the given image couldn't be found and my error image loads, only the onException callback method gets called and hence this, we can't get the error bitmap.

Comment: have you found the solution?

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
Glide.with(context)
.load(uri)
.asBitmap()
.into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(width, height) {
     @Override
     public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
         // add image to the imageView here
     }

     @Override
     public void onLoadFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
         // you are given the error drawable
     }
});
```

Comment: it work,but i can not user .thumbnail() to show loading gif

Comment: What do you mean by .thumbnail()?

Comment: Glide.with(context)
                .load(url)
                .thumbnail(Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.image_loading))
                .into(imageView);

Comment: What happens when you do?